# What will happen if the final ACK for three-way handshake is dropped?

Tags: networking, tcp

Based on [TCP state transition graph](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~agupta/cs340/project2/TCPIP_State_Transition_Diagram.pdf), when server(passive open end) has sent SYN,ACK to client (active open end), and client received it and sent ACK to server, but is dropped in the network, what will happen?

It seems like, client will go into ESTABLISHED state and server won't, but client doesn't know this...

Comment: First, TCP doesn't have servers or clients. The client/server concept is an application concept that TCP doesn't have. TCP sets up connections between peers. Either peer could be the client or server for the application, but TCP doesn't care.

Comment: The server will re-send the SYN/ACK.

Comment: @EJP Any reference for that?

Comment: @RonMaupin I rephrased the terms

Comment: My reference is RFC 793. The SYN part of the SYN-ACK is a TCP segment like any other and is therefore subject to retransmission until ACK'd or the timers expire, at which point the connection is reset.

Answer (score 1):

The SYN/ACK is retransmitted. See RFC 793. The SYN part of the SYN-ACK is a TCP segment like any other, and is therefore subject to retransmission until either it is ACK'd or the timers expire, which causes the connection to be reset.

Comment: Then at this point, client has been already in ESTABLISHED state, thus can send data to the server, but server is not ready yet. So the server will not accept the data, forcing the client resend the data. Until at some point client receives server's SYN-ACK (that is resent), then client will resend the ACK for that. Is my understanding right?

Then the client will be resending two packets at the same time?

Comment: The ACK can be piggy-backed onto the data. I'm not convinced that the server cannot accept the data prior to the ACK being received.